# Unable to see documents in Team Explorer 2013 after upgrade

Tags: tfs

We have upgraded TFS2008 to 2013 on a new server and source control/workitem tracking is okay - we can use all that from within VS2013 Pro.
We have also upgraded Sharepoint (containing all the project documentation) to a new database server and using the TFS 2013 Adminisration Console we can see the Team Projects listed there.

However although from the VS2013 Team Exlorer we can add the team projects and open the 'web portal' for each team project, we cannot see any of the documents nor can we (seemingly) view in a browser the portal that in VS2008 shows the document libraries.

Are we missing something in the unfamiliar interface, or can anyone advise what the cause might be and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to "wire up" the Team Projects to the Sharepoint sites. It sounds like they have been detached through the order of the upgrade.

**Sharepoint needs to be upgraded and available during the upgrade process or this happens**

You can however easily wire them back up. In the Team Project in Visual Studio go to the Team Explorer and do "Settings|Portal".

You should have a dialog for wiring up The existing Sharepoint to the Team Project.

If you don't you may have Tbeen disconnected at the collection level. In which case you can open the TFS Administration Console and follow: http://nakedalm.com/integrate-sharepoint-2013-with-team-foundation-server-2013/

Comment: We have in fact now done it 'the hard way' but thanks for the tip.